Add olcPPolicyConfig to ppolicy overlay
I have an LDAP server, where the ppolicy overlay is already configured.
However it only has the olcOverlayConfig and olcConfig object classes.
I want to add the olcPPolicyConfig objectClass to the olcOverlay, to have the olcPPolicyDefault attribute, but I'm unable to do so.
Usually I get Error: 53 - Unwilling to perform
What I have tried so far:

Add the olcPPolicyConfig only with changetype: modify - add: objectClass
Removing the ppolicy overlay. I was unable to remove it.
Adding all parameters for olcPPolicyConfig, but I read that basically all parameters are optional (for example olcPPolicyDefault).

How can I add these attributes to this config object?
